# Sitecore Webform email issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using sitecore Web Forms for Marketers 2.4.0 rev. 140117, It was working fine but we just noticed that emails are not working fine. Form contains save database and send email actions.

Form's information is saved correctly into database and email is also sent but email body is not replacing the values of the form fields.

here is the HTML generated by the form

Name * should have been replaced with the value entered in the name box but it is not happening, same problem with other fields.

Another issue is that "Insert Field" dropdown on the form is blank, does not contain any field.

```html
<p><strong>Name:&nbsp;</strong>[<label id="{E8A4BF98-DE18-4DB7-B14D-E6DAD00F1872}">Name *</label>]</p>
<p><strong>Email:</strong> [<label id="{3E3DE00D-D804-47F4-AA51-69B7347C95C0}">Email *</label>]
</p>
<p><strong>Phone:&nbsp;</strong>[<label id="{BD908E77-C678-4A81-97DB-AD5D1FC81953}">Phone *</label>]</p>
<p><strong>Post Code:</strong> [<label id="{D6B91F3B-6EC7-4B3A-AE5F-F38ACD158AD8}">Post Code *</label>]</p>
<p><strong>Comments:&nbsp;</strong>[<label id="{0062519C-F761-4323-ADC6-D951734FBEC7}">Comment</label>]</p>
```

here is the generated email html

```html
<p><strong>Name:&nbsp;</strong>[<label id=3D"{E8A4BF98-DE18=
-4DB7-B14D-E6DAD00F1872}">Name *</label>]</p>=0A<p><strong>Email:=
</strong> [<label id=3D"{3E3DE00D-D804-47F4-AA51-69B7347C95C0}">E=
mail *</label>]=0A</p>=0A<p><strong>Phone:&nbsp;</strong>[<label =
id=3D"{BD908E77-C678-4A81-97DB-AD5D1FC81953}">Phone *</label>]</p=
>=0A<p><strong>Post Code:</strong> [<label id=3D"{D6B91F3B-6EC7-4=
B3A-AE5F-F38ACD158AD8}">Post Code *</label>]</p>=0A<p><strong>Com=
ments:&nbsp;</strong>[<label id=3D"{0062519C-F761-4323-ADC6-D9517=
34FBEC7}">Comment</label>]</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this form a copy of an existing one? Verify that the `id` specified in the label matches your form fields. If you did copy the form, delete the Send Email Save Action, then add it back in try to create the message again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that your files are accurate? Start by comparing the dll's in your bin folder with a clean install of the Sitecore/Wffm version (especially wffm in this case). Things like this are often caused by dll's from an older version that get into the bin folder.

Comment: dlls were old, copied from brand new module and all worked.